# InterSystems Caché: How to count encounters of values in list in table?

Tags: sql, collections, count, intersystems-cache

I'm very new to Caché and was asked to count encounters of values in list in table. For example, table looks like this:

```
id | values
-------------------
1  | {1, 2}
2  | {1, 3, 4, 4, 5}
3  | {1, 2, 5}
4  | {1, 2, 2, 4, 5}
5  | {2, 1, 4}
```

Class Definition

```
Class Object.Test Extends %Persistent
{
  Property values As list of %Integer
}
```

And output for that table must look like this:

```
value | count
--------------
 1    |   5
 2    |   5
 3    |   1
 4    |   4
 5    |   3
```

But I have no clue how to do this

**EDIT** Added class definition

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please get yourself familiar with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Nobody will do your work here for you. Show some code, which shows what you tried so far.

Comment: @Konafets, if I had something to show I would but I can only show simple counts when there is no collections in column. I'm pretty much have only basic knowledge with how to work with objects in Caché so that's why I'm asking - I have 0 ideas how to do this

Comment: If you would add class definition for this table, it may help better than this abstract tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have data you need to save.

1. [Project](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_propcoll_sqlproj_alt) list property as a separate table

   `Class Object.Test Extends %Persistent
   {
     Property values As list of %Integer(STORAGEDEFAULT="array", SQLPROJECTION = "table/column");
   }`
2. Delete data, storage definition and recompile the class.
3. Generate the data.
4. Execute SQL query

   `SELECT 
   "values", count(*) AS "count"
   FROM Object.Test_values
   GROUP BY "values"`
5. (Optional) Add and build [collection](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQLOPT_indices#GSQLOPT_indices_collections) indices.

Notes.

That's SQL way. You can also do it:

- object way (iterate over object and their properties)
- global way (iterate over global and this property values)

[Caché commmunity forum](https://community.intersystems.com/).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much